# Using subquery as value in mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm looking for a way to quickly process some table in mysql 5.0.X. I'd like to insert a row into `t1` for each row in `t2`. Essentially, I'd like something like this to map over every row:

```
REPLACE INTO t1 VALUES (CONCAT('blah/', (select username from t2)), 'value')
```

Is that possible without procedures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
REPLACE INTO t1
SELECT CONCAT('blah/',username), 'value'
FROM t2
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for the `INSERT SELECT` statement unless I am misunderstanding.
Check [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)
 for details.